# The recursion principle.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the book that I read there is a exercise where we need to prove the recursion principle that is written in the next fashion.

**Proposition**: Let $f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a function and $c \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, there exist a unique function $ a: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that: $a(0):=c\: $ and  $\:a(n^{+}):=f(n,a(n))$; (where $n^{+}:=n \cup \left\{n \right\} $).

The book give us a hint: Show that for each natural number there exist a *n-function*  $ a_{n}: n^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ such that $a_{n}(0):=c\: $ and for each $ i \in n$, $\:a_{n}(i^{+}):=f(i,a(i))$.

And here is what I have at this moment:

**Claim 1**: For each natural number there exist a n-function.

Proof of Claim 1: Let  "$\varphi (x)$" be the following:

$ \forall x \forall y \forall y' ( \langle x,y\rangle  \in a_{n} \wedge \langle x,y'\rangle  \in a_{n} \rightarrow y=y' ) \wedge Dom(a_{n}) = n^{+} \wedge a_{n} (0)= c \,\wedge \,  \forall i (i \in n \rightarrow a_{n} (i^{+}) = f(\,i,a_{n} (i))\,). $

Now we can apply the separation axiom and form a set which we define as:
$ S : = \left\{n \in \mathbb{N}: \exists a_{n} \varphi (x) \right\} $

For n=0, we require a function with domain $ 0^{+} $. And as the only element of the domain is $ 0 $, we can form the ordered pair $ a_0 = \left\{ \langle 0, c\rangle \right\}. $ Which is a function, its domain is in fact $n^{+}$ and the last statement of the formula is vacously true. Then $ 0 \in S$.

Suppose $ n\in S $ that means $ a_{n} $ exist. Then, we define  $ a_{n^{+}} $ as follows:

$ a_{n^{+}}: = a_{n}  \cup \left\{ \langle n^{+}, f(n,a_{n} (n)) \rangle \right\}$.

So, only we need to show that  $ a_{n^{+}} $ is a n+1- function.

i) $ \langle x,y \rangle \in a_{n^{+}} \leftrightarrow \langle x,y \rangle \in  a_{n} \vee  \langle x,y \rangle \in \left\{ \langle n^{+}, f(n,a_{n} (n)) \rangle \right\}$

As $ a_{n}$ is a function by our inductive hypothesis, only we need to show that $ \left\{ \langle n^{+}, f(n,a_{n} (n)) \rangle \right\} $ is a functional relation:

$\langle x,y \rangle \in \left\{ \langle n^{+}, f(n,a_{n} (n)) \rangle \right\} \wedge \langle x,y' \rangle \in \left\{ \langle n^{+}, f(n,a_{n} (n)) \rangle \right\} \rightarrow y = f(n,a_{n} (n) = y'$. It follows because f is indeed a function.

ii) $ Dom (a_{n^{+}}) = Dom(a_{n}) \cup \left\{ n^{+} \right\} $.  By hypothesis we know that $ Dom(a_{n}) = n^{+} $. Hence  $  n^{+} \cup \left\{ n^{+} \right\} = n^{++}$.

iii) As $a_{n}\subset a_{n ^ {+}} $, and by hypothesis we know that $\langle 0,c \rangle \in a_{n} $. Then  $\langle 0,c \rangle \in a_{n ^ {+}} $.

iv) $\forall i \in n^{+}. \langle i^{+},c \rangle \in a_{n ^ {+}} \leftrightarrow \langle i^{+},c \rangle \in a_{n} \vee \langle i^{+},c \rangle \in \left\{ \langle n^{+}, f(n,a_{n} (n)) \rangle \right\}  $.

If $ \langle i^{+},c \rangle \in a_{n} $ by hypothesis we know that  $ c = f(i, a_{n}(i)) $ as desired. On the other hand if $\langle i^{+},c \rangle \in \left\{ \langle n^{+}, f(n,a_{n} (n)) \rangle \right\}$ it follows by construction.

Then $ n^{+} \in S $, and we conclude by induction that, there exist a n-function for every natural number.

**Claim 2**: For each natural number this function is unique.

Proof of claim 2: 
For n = 0, the only 0-function is $ a_0 = \left\{ \langle 0, c\rangle \right\} $. If we assume that holds for n, we need to show that also holds for $ n^{+} $.

Let $ a_n = a'_n $, for construction of n-functions we know that:

$ a_{n^{+}} = a_{n}  \cup \left\{ \langle n^{+}, f(n,a_{n} (n)) \rangle \right\} =a'_{n}  \cup \left\{ \langle n^{+}, f(n,a'_{n} (n)) \rangle \right\} =a'_{n^{+}} $. Therefore all the n-functions are uniques.

> At this point  I'm not sure how could I derive exactly the  function 
>   a, I think that maybe using the union of all the families  $ a_{n} $.
>   But I'm not really sure, somebody knows?

---

I'm not sure here, but if we use the replacement axiom for each n-function we have:

Let "$\varphi (x,y)$" be the formula:

$  ( x \in \mathbb{N} \wedge y = \,x-function ) \vee (\neg x \in \mathbb{N} \wedge y = 0 ) $.

For the claim 2 there exist a unique n-function for each n, therefore "$\varphi (x,y)$" is functional. And we can apply replacement to derive: $\left\{a_{n}: n\in  \mathbb{N} \right\}$.

And (maybe) define the function $a$  to be: $a: = \bigcup \left\{a_{n}: n\in  \mathbb{N} \right\}$

Here is my attempt: By the union axiom and the replacement schema axiom $a$ defined as above is a set. So, only we need to show that indeed is a function and that all property that we wish really holds.

**Claim 3**: The relation a is a functional relation.

Proof of Claim  3: To $a$ be a functional relation we need to show $ \langle x,y \rangle \in a \wedge  \langle x,y' \rangle \in a \rightarrow y = y'.$

if $\langle x,y \rangle \in a \leftrightarrow \exists n \in \mathbb{N}. \langle x,y \rangle \in a_{n} $ at the same way $\langle x,y' \rangle \in a \leftrightarrow \exists m \in \mathbb{N}. \langle x,y' \rangle \in a_{m}. $ And as $ m \in n \vee n\in m  \vee n = m$.

(1) If $n = m$, by claim 2 we have that $ a_{n} = a_{m}$ and as $ a_{n} $ is functional. We're done, that means $ y = y'$ because  $\langle x,y \rangle \in a_{n} \wedge \langle x,y' \rangle \in a_{n} \rightarrow y = y'$.

(2) If  $ m \in n\, (m < n)$  by construction we know that $ a_{m} \subset a_{n}$. Then $\langle x,y' \rangle \in a_{m} \rightarrow \langle x,y' \rangle \in a_{n} $. As  $ \langle x,y \rangle \in a_{n} \wedge \langle x,y' \rangle \in a_{n} $  and as $a_{n}$ is functional. Then $ y = y' $ as desired.

(3) At the same way if  $ n \in m\, (n < m),\, a_{n} \subset a_{m}$. Then $\langle x,y \rangle \in a_{n} \rightarrow \langle x,y \rangle \in a_{m} $. As  $ \langle x,y \rangle \in a_{m} \wedge \langle x,y' \rangle \in a_{m} $  and as $a_{m}$ is functional. Then $ y = y' $ as desired.

Then $a$ is a functional relation.

**Claim 4**: The functional relation a, is a function such that $ a(0) = c \wedge a (i^{+}) = f(i, a(i))$.

Proof of claim 4:

(1) As definition all the n-function evaluated at 0 are c, therefore the union of all of them is c, $ \langle 0,c \rangle \in a $ as desired.

(2) If  $i^{+} \in \mathbb{N}. \langle i^{+},y \rangle \in a \leftrightarrow \exists n\in \mathbb{N}. \langle i^{+},y \rangle \in a_{n}. $ By construction of all the n-function that means $ y = f(i, a_{n} (i))$. So, only we need to show that $ a_{n} (i) = a (i) $. But since $ a_{n} $ is the restriction of $a$ at n, that follows inmediately.

What do you think? Is it correct?

---

The other exercise the book says this:

Show using the last proposition there exist only one version of the natural numbers in set theory.

My attempt: Let $ \mathbb{N'}$ be a set such that the Peano's axioms hold. Let f be a function, $f : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N'} \rightarrow  \mathbb{N'} $, such that $ \langle n,n' \rangle \mapsto n'^{+}$. And, $ a: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N'}$ such that, $a(0) = 0'$ and $ a(n^{+}) = f(n, a(n)) = n'^{+} =(a(n))^{+} $. By the last proposition the function exist and it is unique.

Injective part:

For $n = 0$ we have $ a (0) = a(0^{*}) = 0'$, so we need to show that $0 = 0^{*}$. By the sake of the contradiction suppose $0 \neq 0^{*}$. Therefore $ 0^{*} = k^{+} $ for some $k \in \mathbb{N},\, a(0^{*})=a(k^{+}) = k'^{+}$. And as the Peano's Axiom hold in $\mathbb{N'}, k'^{+} \neq 0'$, a contradiction. Then, $ 0=0^{*} $.

Suppose that our assumption holds for n, we need to show that also holds for $ n^{+} $. If
$ n'^{+}=a (n^{+}) = a (n^{*+})=n'^{*+}$. By the Peano's axioms we have $ n'^{+} = n'^{*+} \rightarrow  n'= n'^{*}$. As $a(n)=n' = a(n^{*})=n'^{*},\; a(n) = a(n^{*}) \rightarrow n = n^{*} $ (by the inductive hypothesis). Hence $ n^{+} = n^{*+}$. That closed the induction.

Surjective part:

By definition we know that $0' = a (0)$, so there exist a $0 \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose that our assumption holds for n', that means $ n' = a(n)$ there exist a $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So, $ n' ^{+}=(n')^{+} = (a(n))^{+} = a(n^{+})$. That closed the induction.

Hence exist a bijection between them.

Any suggestion about all of these exercises....

Comment: I don't know what an $n$-function is but if you're allowed to use the usual principle of recursive definition then you should.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff This is a specific *application* of that principle. I see that he's going through all the steps to prove the principle for this special case, which looks like overkill.

Comment: @dfeuer Heh, true. I read all this too quickly.

Comment: @dfeuer An $n$ function seems to be a function with domain $n^{+}$ mapping to the naturals.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Exactly that is what the book define them. Any function with domain $ n^{+}$ such that $\varphi (x)$ is true.

Comment: Do you think is this correct? I mean, the proof is legitimate or maybe need some change. I'll need that proof to show in other exercise derived of it, that there exist a bijection between the natural numbers and any other system such that the Peano's Axiom holds. I think is easier to do that :P

Comment: Not familiar with your notation. Assuming you want to prove the existence of unique $a:N\to N$ such that:

$a(0)=c$ and $a(n+1)=f(n,a(n))$. 


I would construct the set $a$ of ordered pairs of natural numbers such that: 

$\forall m,n:[(m,n)\in a \iff (m,n)\in N^2 $

$\land \forall d\subset N^2:[(c,0)\in d \land \forall p,q:[(p,q)\in d \implies (p+1,f(p,q))\in d]] \implies (m,n)\in d]$

Then prove $a$ is the required function.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of the recursion theorem for $\Bbb N$ looks spot-on. Good job, this proof is nontrivial to write correctly :).

---

In the second exercise, you take an overly long route, as well as glance over the proof that $a(n) = n'$.

If you first prove by induction on $\Bbb N$ that $a(n) = n'$, then injectivity is immediate.

Subsequently take $S = \{n' \in \Bbb N': \exists m: a(m) = n'\}$ and conclude surjectivity by induction on $\Bbb N'$. (This is actually more or less identical to what you wrote.)